# Installing ffmpeg on offline 14.04 servers

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ffmpeg

I have some Ubuntu 14.04 **servers** (that is, headless, no UI involved) that for security reasons cannot be connected to the internet, but they need `ffmpeg` installed on them.

Typically, for an `ffmpeg` install on Ubuntu 14.04 I use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

On 14.04 its necessary to add the `mc3man/trusty-media` repo since `ffmpeg` was intentionally omitted from the 14.04 official repos.

I'm wondering what I need to do to get `ffmpeg` and any of its transitive dependencies loaded onto a USB stick and then subsequently installed on my non-networked/offline 14.04 servers and running correctly.

It looks like `ffmpeg` usually installs itself to `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`, so on one hand it *could* be as easy as copying that binary to the flash drive. However I'm wondering if it has any dependencies that would need to be copied over as well. I'm also wondering if it matters *where* on the offline servers I install/save the binaries to (does it?). I figure as long as the system path can find `ffmpeg`, it shouldn't matter if I install it under `usr/bin/ffmpeg` or `/opt/ffmpeg`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @bodhi.zazen (+1) however I'm going to push back and argue this is *not* a duplicate of that, since the question + answer were both for 14.04 desktops (not headless servers). Here, I have to do *everything* from the command-line, both on the Ubuntu 14.04 server that I'm acquiring the binaries from, as well as the non-networked/offline Ubuntu 14.04 servers I'm installing those binaries on. Make sense?

Comment: No, follow any of the command line instructions in the various answers.

Comment: @smeeb This answer doesn't need GUI http://askubuntu.com/a/1016/396145 of course you need another pc.

Comment: Thanks @bodhi.zazen but still not seeing what you're seeing (and I **am** trying!). Can you provide the link to a particular answer that you think already addresses my question? I think you'll find that none of those answers will work for me because `ffmpeg` is not in the official Ubuntu repos for 14.04.

Comment: They all work. Add in the repo. https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware - see step 3 for manually adding a repo / ppa

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [download a static build of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and put it on your USB stick to distribute to your unconnected servers.

Comment: +1 for easiest installation without internet connection

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you need to install ffmpeg, you could try compiling it using this guide

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

make sure you got installed this dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev
```

Downloaded and installed with `dpkg -i` (each one of them) and well, now that we are there, why not

```
dpkg -i name_of_ffmpeg_package.deb
```